# Uninstall VS2008 after VS2010 Upgrade?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I recently bought and installed VS2010 Professional **Upgrade** on a system where I had VS2008 installed.   I had been told on a Microsoft discussion forum that the Upgrade version required VS2008 to already be installed.   Fine.

So now that it's done I still have VS2008 sitting there, taking up space, even though I'm using VS2010.   Is there any harm or nasty side-effects in UNinstalling VS2008?   Will it break anything about VS2010 because it's an Upgrade version?

PS - This question seems to have totally stumped them on social.msdn.microsoft.com !

Answer (score 0):

[Crystal Reports isn’t part of VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197735/crystal-reports-not-included-in-visual-studio-2010-what-are-the-consequences-fo). Maybe you get trouble if your projects use them…